# Could not install python package due to OSError: Permission denied

Tags: python, pandas, virtualenv, python-dateutil

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\path\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\dateutil\zoneinfo\dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz'
Check the permissions.

This is the error I get when trying to install pandas.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled python 3 times for the latest version and tried all of the methods i have found so far.

I have tried.

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Then it says try the --user option.

I try

```
pip3 install pandas --user
```

and the same error occurs.

I even set up a virtual env in vscode. And i went into the pyvenv.cfg and turned the

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

to

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

I still get the same error. With permission denied. It goes from Errno 13. To Winerror 5. Access denied.

And not only that. So i get that error. So i go to where that error is in the venv. and it's not there. the  'dateutil-zoneinfo.tar.gz' is not there.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled python 3 times for the latest version and tried all of the methods i have found so far.

I have tried.

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Then it says try the --user option.

I try

```
pip3 install pandas --user
```

and the same error occurs.

I even set up a virtual env in vscode. And i went into the pyvenv.cfg and turned the

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

to

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```

I still get the same error. With permission denied. It goes from Errno 13. To Winerror 5. Access denied.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Windows, and that you have admin privs due to the fact that you could install python. So when you launch command prompt, or whatever terminal your using, select "run as administrator".

Please accept this as the correct answer if it solves your problem so that other people can find the solution as well.

Comment: Hey so I tried it and it didn't work ;(